# Show tooltip arrow at top of icon which is align end of text in TextView

Tags: android, tooltip

I have a `TextView` in which i am setting text dynamically(text length is not fixed ) and end of the text there is a icon,So My question is I want to show `tooltip` like `tooltip` arrow should be at top of info icon , as shown in attached image

[image]
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way

**XML File**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/clMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvShipInBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Ship in Box($10 Extra per box)"
        android:textColor="#E83535"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivDone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvShipInBox" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/clToolTip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_tooltip_bg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/clMain"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.075"

    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/clMain"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.65">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.87"
        android:text="A box increases an items volumetric weight and costs more."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java File**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ivInfo;
    ConstraintLayout clToolTip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ivInfo = findViewById(R.id.ivInfo);
        clToolTip = findViewById(R.id.clToolTip);
        ivInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ivInfo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ivInfo.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        clToolTip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 7000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```